# Need help in Geo-RSS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, georss

I am new to GeoRSS (& RSS also) and I have created [small sample](http://jsfiddle.net/977Sj/) which displaying latest earthquake on map.

According to [GeoRSS definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoRSS)/concept, it is showing the feeds across the world using latitude, longitude information but I am not able to see that information in xml file.

I am using [this xml](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs7day-M5.xml) file so the feeds are really coming from that place or somebody updating/replying that information in xml file

Going through [this](http://www.geonames.org/rss-to-georss-converter.html) link and trying to understand the workflow (how the RSS feed get lat,lon from Geo-names database.

Any help regarding this like answer/explanation will be great!!

Comment: When you say that you cannot see the lat long in the file, are you trying to look at he url in Firefox\a web browser? Most Modern Browsers will not show a RSS feed in a pure form. To see the actual data, try to use curl\wget to download the file from the URL, and then see it in a text editor.

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe Thanks I will check and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first link each item contains a latitude and longitude.

```
<geo:lat>16.6829</geo:lat>
<geo:long>40.7946</geo:long>
```

which are what changes it from an RSS feed to a GeoRSS feed.

The GeoNames page is for converting basic text RSS feeds (like latest news) into GeoRSS feeds by spotting names and guessing where the news item is about and adding the required location.

So in you example change it to say:

```
var georssUrl = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs7day-M5.xml";
```

zoom out abit (there were no large earthquakes in your AOI) and they are there.

For more discussion and the spec see http://georss.org/

Comment: ♦ Thanks for the  explanation. Few questions to you :                                                        1.Should I assign xml directly in georssurl OR use the Geo-names url then append xml?                              2.I can not see every xml in the map I tried that.      3.In some cases its showing some different location like news in India but I can see the feeds in the US or Australia.